# Magento2.2.5 Luma child theme not using default_head_blocks.xml in child theme folder

Tags: magento-2.2.5, luma-theme, parent-child-theme

I have a Magento 2.2.5 based multi-store view website. What we want to do is take the Luma theme and create a custom child theme from it. Each store view (we have 3) would use its own child theme of the Luma theme.

The main difference is each child theme needs to use its own CSS file and some js files. The issue is even though I did an upgrade, compiled, deploy and assigned my theme to the store views my default_head_blocks.xml file does not seem to be loading from the child theme folder.

My folder structure is below.
app/design/frontend/Kiss/
  Then in the "Kiss" folder, I have 4 child theme folders
     luma
     storea_luma
     storeb_luma
     storec_luma

there are some files in the "luma" folder that I will have all 3 store views reference while other files will be referenced from the individual child theme folders.

so, for example, the footer related files for all three store views would ideally be loaded from the luma folder because it should be the same for all 3 store views.

My default_head_blocks.xml located in app/design/frontend/Kiss/sotrec_luma/web/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

now when I go to storec_luma store view and view console I don't see any of the files that are called in via the XML file??

I have read conflicting posts about the Luma theme can not be inherited.
just wondering what the above issue might be that's preventing my XML from loading in the store view.